# Breeze.js and PreserveReferencesHandling serializing failure

Tags: breeze

I encounter a problem with deserializing entities in client side with breeze.js.
My data model entity has one to many relation to other entities (A has ICollection of B)
When I make a query , I see the data returned from the server include $ref= # , I understood breeze uses this to identify same objects returned from the server.
But in client side all those entities with $ref=# doesn't deserialized properly I get this function () { return mc.refMap[node]} insted to get the real object in client side .

Here is my object structure :

```
public partial class Product
    {        
        public Product()
        {            
            this.ProductCatalogue = new HashSet<ProductCatalogue>();
            this.DiameterRanges = new HashSet<DiameterRanges>();            
            this.Product_Children = new HashSet<Product>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }         
        public string Code { get; set; } 

        public virtual ICollection<ProductCatalogue> ProductCatalogue { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<DiameterRanges> DiameterRanges { get; set; }
        public virtual Product Product_Parent { get; set; }        
    }

    public partial class DiameterRanges
    {   
        public int Id { get; set; } 
        public double MinSPH { get; set; } 
        public double MaxSPH { get; set; } 
        public double MinCyl { get; set; } 
        public double MaxCyl { get; set; } 
        public short MinDiameter { get; set; } 
        public short MaxDiameter { get; set; } 
        public int Product_Id { get; set; } 

        public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    }
```

Nothing special in my server side query : Context.Product.Include("DiameterRanges");
Any idea to figure out this problem .

Thanks in advance ....

Comment: Can you see DiameterRanges class in metadata?

Comment: Ok, I made some debugging using fiddler about the data returned from the server . I see in the products list returned references that doesn't exist in the main list . Say we have 10 products . I see for example the third product in the list is $ref = 12 , and I have no product in the list with $id = 12 , so I think this is the problem , but how can this be happen in the server side query .